# "За спеціальністю" чи "зі спеціальності"?

Tags: вживання-слів, різниця-між-словами, прийменники

Cлово [«спеціальність»](http://sum.in.ua/s/specialjnistj)
згідно із СУМ-11 означає:

> 1. **Окрема галузь науки, техніки, мистецтва і т. ін.; сфера чиєїсь діяльності або вивчення чого-небудь.** Потім признався [Адаменко], що його спеціальність — медицина, а в армії був за ветеринарного фельдшера (Ю. Янов., II, 1958, 246); — До війни я був лектором. Моя спеціальність — історичний матеріалізм… (Перв., Дикий мед, 1963, 275); **// Основна кваліфікація; професія, фах.** Набув [Захар] сталої спеціальності (Ле, Право.., 1957, 231); Потрібні йому були різні люди: і лікарі, і цирульники, і теслярі, і ливарники, і архітектори, і каменярі, і друкарі — різні майстри різних спеціальностей (Ів., Таємниця, 1959, 172); Лелекач був добрим майстром-мебельником. Але не працював за спеціальністю (Томч., Закарп. опов., 1953, 192); **// розм. Улюблена справа, заняття, в якому хто-небудь виявляє уміння, хист.** Тепер за тобою установиться спеціальність писати біографічні реферати (Л. Укр., V, 1956, 222); Умів Юрчик оповідати як ніхто! Славився тим. А спеціальністю його були оповідання про Довбуша (Хотк., II, 1966, 153).
> 2. Властивість за знач. спеціа́льний 2. Спеціальність терміна.

І коли хочемо у своєму висловлюванні вказати на те, згідно з чим, відповідно до чого відбувається дія, то вживаємо словосполучення за моделлю «прийменник „за“ + спеціальність в орудному відмінку», наприклад:

> працювати за спеціальністю, шукати роботу за спеціальністю.

А в яких випадках доречніше та правильніше користуватися конструкцією «прийменник „зі“ + спеціальність»?

Answer (score 1):

> У тому ж разі, коли треба підкреслити галузь знань, дисципліну, до
>   якої хто-, що-небудь має якесь відношення, то послуговуються
>   конструкцією «прийменника (зі) + спеціальність у родовому відмінку»,
>   як-от: іспит зі спеціальності «менеджмент зовнішньоекономічної
>   діяльності», місячні курси зі спеціальності «бухоблік». Або: «Така
>   література потрібна майбутнім фахівцям із спеціальностей
>   «комп’ютеризовані інтегровані системи і робототехніка», «технологія
>   виробництва» (з журн.).

[Культура мови](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine60-32.pdf)